# Image is picked from gallery but not viewed

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz app in which I have a profile page were the user can change their image when they needed. It was working properly, the profile page of the user is a fragment not an activity. I faced a problem recently that am able to pick image from gallery but cannot view it the fragment image view instead of viewing that fragment my last (i.e) the activity before this fragment is called. Can anyone please help me reg this.. ?

Let me explain my prob clearly:
I have a navigation drawer activity which contains four fragments. first I have a splash screen activity next comes the navigation were one of the fragment appears, which contains a couple of `onClickListeners()` in it which navigates to the corresponding activity. What I did here is when I press back button from the fragment I got the recently viewed activity since I killed that activity life cycle by giving `finish()`.

Here raised the next problem, now when I try to press back button I got the fragment itself viewed and then the app got closed. For this I found a solution of giving `finish()` in `onstop()` in my navigation activity which holds all the fragments. So now that problem got solved for me.

Again I got another issue (i.e) in that four fragments one is profile page, where the user can update their profile photo from gallery. The problem here is when I try to change the profile photo it goes inside the gallery and when I picked a image, the fragment life cycle `onStop()` method is called and the app gets closed by itself.  I want to stop this from happening.. please have a look and suggest me with some ideas.

Comment: add code.......

Comment: Would you please mind showing what have you code so far ?

Comment: Actually am confused which part of code i will post here. Because it was working fine before i added onStop() to finish the fragments life cycle.

Comment: Is there any way to retian the state of the profile page ?